# Want to delete the files using Bat file

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete the temp files every sunday automatically using bat file. Location is C:/xxx/yyy/temp.
Could you help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
DEL /S "C:/xxx/yyy/temp/*"
```

Place it in a .bat file and use the windows task scheduler to do it every sunday.

Excuse me for my English, I'm not a native speaker

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. It needs task scheduler to automate the task. But Main objectives of Batch programming are automating the task and maintaining the log file only know.

Comment: you can create a scheduled task with batch. See `schtasks /create /?` It's not easy to find the right syntax, if you do it the very first time, but it's definitely worth investing some time to find out.

Answer (score 0):

A batch file can't run itself at a set time, that's what the task scheduler is for. You can use the gui to set it up, or if you really want to deploy it with a batch file, you can put this in one and run it:

```
at 10:00am /every:monday "del /s /q C:\xxx\yyy\temp"
```

Comment: The `at` command has been replaced with `schtasks` in later versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have this as a batch file the only problem is that it will do it every day. You will ether need to find a way to make it run just on a Sunday or let it run every day.

```
@echo off
:no
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=:,. " %%i in ("%time%") do (
set hr=%%i
set mn=%%j
set sc=%%k
)
cls
echo %hr%
echo %mn%
echo %sc%
:Test1
IF %hr% == 10 goto Test2
timeout /t 30>nul
goto no
:Test2
IF %mn% == 00 goto yes
timeout /t 30>nul
goto no
:yes
DEL /S "C:/xxx/yyy/temp/*"
timeout /t 61>nul
goto no
```